# Symbol similar to \equiv

Tags: math-operators

What's the command for typing 3 lines exactly like `\equiv` but with index in the middle of top line? Thanks.

EDIT:
this is the symbol I meant
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Have you tried [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) to look up the symbol of interest? (I must confess not knowing what 'index in the middle of top line" is supposed to look like.)

Comment: I've updated post with image of the symbol. And yes I've tried detexify but no result.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this "precomposed" symbol doesn't exist.  you might take a look at `\stackrel` (basic latex command) or `\overset` (requires `amsmath`) to construct it yourself.

Comment: Thanks ;) `overset{0}{\equiv}` did it.

Comment: As Barbara writes, create a command if you are using it often; `\newcommand*\horse[1]{\overset{#1}{\equiv}}` and then type `\horse{0}`.

Answer (score 4):

this does not exist as a "precomposed" symbol.  however, `amsmath` provides a mechanism for creating combinations of this sort -- `\overset`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$ x \overset{0}{\equiv} y $
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

when `\overset` is applied to a single symbol, the proper class of that symbol
(e.g., `\mathrel`, `\mathbin`) is recognized automatically, so there is no need
to specify it.

of course, if the compound symbol is to be used more than once, it's a good idea
to define a command to access it.